# User name empty when sending notification with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I want to send notification to users when they receive new messages with the below JavaScript code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{user_id}/{message_id}').onWrite( (change, context) => {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const message_id = context.params.message_id;

console.log('We Have A Notification for :', user_id);

if (!change.after.val()){
    return console.log("A Notification Has Been Deleted From The Database: ", message_id)
}

const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/messages/${user_id}/${message_id}`).once('value');

return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

    const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;
    console.log("You have new notification from : ", from_user_id)

    const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${from_user_id}/name`).once('value');
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

    return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {

        const userName = result[0].val();
        const token_id = result[1].val();

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Chat+",
                body: `You have a new notification from ${userName}`,
                icon: "default",
                click_action: "com.mani.eric.quickch_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
            },

        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload ).then(Response =>{ 
            console.log('this is the notification')
        });


    });

});

});
```

the notification actually gets delivered but on both devices(sender and receiver gets same notification) with the user name of the sender as null.

my question now is, how can i retrieve the sender user name and display the notification only on the receivers device?

Answer (score 0):

You have a type on the path that triggers the function:

```
functions.database.ref('/messages/{user_id/{message_id}')
```

Should be:

```
functions.database.ref('/messages/{user_id}/{message_id}')
```

So with a closing parenthesis after `user_id`.

Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as the code you shared is quite a bit more complex than needed to reproduce the problem. For example, your `console.log('We Have A Notification for :', user_id);` already should show that `user_id` is null, so the code after that can't work, and is irrelevant to the problem. Reducing the scope of the problem this way increases the chances that you'll find the cause yourself. Or at worst, it reduces the code we need to look at, which increases the chance that somebody will spot the problem and answer.

Comment: that was actually a typo that occurred when i was typing this  code. the original code i have here is this `functions.database.ref('/messages/{user_id}/{message_id}')`